# Clear the SelectedValue from a ComboBox automatically when it is not part of the ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have `ComboBoxes` in my WPF application that get selected by using the `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath`. Sometimes the `SelectedValue` is not part of the `ItemsSource` (because the database is inconsistent).

Example:

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
{
    new Item() { Id = "1", Text = "Text 1" },
    new Item() { Id = "2", Text = "Text 2" },
};

SelectedValue = "3";
```

When the `ComboBox` is loaded and no other value is selected, the `SelectedValue` property is still the inconsistent value ("3" in the example). Is there a way to let the binding automatically clear the `SelectedValue` when it is not a part of the `ItemsSource`?

View:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
              SelectedValuePath="Id" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="Text" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
        {
            new Item() {Id ="1", Text = "Text 1" },
            new Item() {Id ="2", Text = "Text 2" },
        };

        SelectedValue = "3";
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Item> items;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set { items = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string selectedValue;

    public string SelectedValue
    {
        get { return selectedValue; }
        set { selectedValue = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: This logic should be implemented in the view model, i.e. you should never set the SelectedValue to 3 when there is no such item in the ItemsSource. Then you set your view model into an invalid state.

Comment: I don't think there's any safe assumption they can make about what's valid there. The viewmodel might want to have multiple potential invalid values, for example. Your SelectedValue property setter will have to enforce this.

Comment: IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" and use SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue

Comment: @blindmeis I tried this too and even though the ComboBox shows the first item selected, the underlying SelectedItem is still the invalid one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This logic should be implemented in the view model, i.e. you should never set the `SelectedValue` to 3 when there is no such item in `Items`. Then you set your view model into an invalid state.

So instead of trying to implement this kind of logic in the view or the control you should implement it in the view model where it belongs. It should be very simple:

```
SelectedValue = "3";
if (!Items.Any(x => x.Id == SelectedValue))
    SelectedValue = null;
```

Or in the setter:

```
public string SelectedValue
{
    get { return selectedValue; }
    set
    {
        selectedValue = value;
        if (!Items.Any(x => x.Id == SelectedValue))
            selectedValue = null;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll do it manually for each SelectedValue property. I half expected there would be some binding option that validated the current SelectedValue. Thank you for your answer!